# Passing the shell script through the function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, razor, active-directory

I am creating an application to manage ad groups through MVC using Power Shell Script Interaction. I have created a function that will return the values to fill in the razor components of HTML. However, when I passing the shell scripts from the base directory location the component is not getting filled with the value.

I have tried to set the path of the script using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, there is no error being generated nor I am getting any output.

** Razor Code **

```
@functions {

    public string PowerShellExecutor(string script) {
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        string outString = "";
        shell.Commands.AddScript(script);
        var results = shell.Invoke();
        if (results.Count>0)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var psObj in results)
            {
                builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

            }
            outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
        }
        return outString;
    }


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextBox("txtDir", @PowerShellExecutor(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()+ "Shell\\Get-StewardName.ps1"), new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.TextBox("txtDirectory", @PowerShellExecutor("$env:USERDNSDOMAIN") , new { @class = "form-control"})*@
     </div>
 </div>
```

** Powershell Script **

```
    $StewardName = Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Properties DisplayName | Select -ExpandProperty DisplayName
    $EmployeeNumber = Get-ADUser $env:UserName -Properties EmployeeNumber| Select -ExpandProperty EmployeeNumber
    Write-Output "Steward: $StewardName ($EmployeeNumber)"
```

When I type the environment variables I get the domain I am member of. When I pass script it should be getting some value.

Comment: Unrelated: Cut your AD calls in half with `$ADUser=Get-ADUser $env:username -Properties DisplayName,EmployeeNumber; Write-Output "StewardName: $($ADUser.DisplayName) ($($ADUser.EmployeeNumber))"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"\\Shell\\Get-StewardName.ps1"`?

Comment: Nops still not working...! I think it has something to do with Variables that is why it is not able to fetch values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so replacing AddScript() with AddCommand() executes the script however, while using environment variables to fetch the data it throws command not found exception.